# Troubles with differentiation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Consider
$$ I(r)=\int_0^1\frac{x^r\log^2x}{\log^2x+4\pi^2}dx$$
With some work, one can show that
$$I(r)=\frac{1}{r+1}-\pi^2+2\pi\text{Si}((r+1)2\pi)$$
with $\text{Si}(x)$ being the sine integral, and [Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C3%5DPower%5Blog%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Blog%2C2%5D%2B4Power%5Bpi%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D).

Now, consider the integral
$$J(r)=\int_0^1\frac{x^r\log x}{\log^2x+4\pi^2}dx$$
[According to Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C3%5Dlog%2CPower%5Blog%2C2%5D%2B4Power%5Bpi%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D), we have
$$ J(r) = \text{Ci}((r+1)2\pi)$$
with $\text{Ci}(x)$ being the cosine integral.

However, notice that, **when expressed as integrals**, we have
$$ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}J(r)=I(r)$$
but this is clearly **not true when applied to the results of the integrals**:
$$ \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\text{Ci}((r+1)2\pi)\neq \frac{1}{r+1}-\pi^2+2\pi\text{Si}((r+1)2\pi)$$
But why? It doesn't seem that something is wrong with the results, since numerical integration agrees with them.

Please provide some clarification on **why the derivatives don't match**. Thank you.

Comment: Use the representation $$\frac{\log x}{\log^2 x+4\pi^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(\log(x)u)e^{-2\pi u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$ to evaluate $$J(r)=-\pi\sin(2\pi r)+\frac{1}{2}e^{2\pi ir}\mathrm{Ei}(-2\pi i(1+r))+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2\pi ir}\mathrm{Ei}(2\pi i(1+r)).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't checked the result of the first integral. But there seems to be an error in the second, as checked by [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C4.5%5Dlog%2CPower%5Blog%2C2%5D%2B4Power%5Bpi%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D)

As you can see $J(4.5)=-\text{Ci}(11\pi)$

Also, a quick Wolfram Script shows this:

[image]

I believe your solution only holds for some particular choices of $r$. But to get the differentiation right, it has to hold over a continuous range of values for $r$

I would go so far as to say that your results holds true for all whole number values of $r$, as shown here:
[image]

[At the risk of sounding impudent, I'd suggest relying on CAS only for numerical methods, or as a last resource. They're great for empirical work, but not for actual mathematical thinking, at least in my opinion]

Comment: Thank you, discontinuity was my only guess as well, but couldn't check if it was correct. 
I know CAS sometimes fail, but in this case I knew that the result was correct for at least integer values of $r$, so I assumed incorrectly it was true for every $r$.

Comment: @Zima By the way, if you are interested in using CAS, then learning WolframScript might come as a handy tool.

Comment: Their [introductory tutorials](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) are pretty great too.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You’re welcome! :)